# Why is there a minimum current in a class-a chopper?

Tags: power-supply, current, power-electronics, thyristor, class-a

$$i_o(t) = {{{V - E} \over {R}} \cdot (1-e^{-{R \over L}\cdot t}) + I_{min} \cdot {e^{-{R \over L}\cdot t}}}$$

Where is the minimum current from, and why are we dividing by R?

[image][image]

This is the link
https://slideplayer.com/amp/5291078/

Comment: Please provide more context (circuit schematic, where you got the equation from, etc.). As is, there isn't really enough information for provide an answer.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust images taken from a site called note shit.com

Comment: I understand Laplace but don't understand the second equation. I didn't trust it either but please trust it I've confirmed it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Images from [electrical4U.com](https://www.electrical4u.com/chopper-dc-to-dc-converter/): -

A Class-A chopper circuit: -

[image]

[image]

Note that \$I_0\$ (when stabilized after the start-up transient)) varies between a maximum value (aka peak) and a minimum value (aka valley).

> *Where is the minimum current from*

The valley is the minimum current. If you want to know why R divides into the equation, you need to link to the source material used in your question.